# Confusion related to power in series circuit

Tags: voltage, power

Two 100W, 100V lamps are connected in series across 200V supply. The power consumed by each lamp in watts will be?

My attempt - According to me voltage divided half half and each bulb get 100V and produce 100 watt.

I found same question with solution on google. But solution is not clear.

Doubt 1-

When they are finding resistance of each bulb they are using 200V but why not using 100V as voltage of lamp is 100V and we are finding its resistance.

Doubt 2-

I think voltage is divided in series circuits based on voltage of equipments i.e lamps here. So why not 200V is divided into 100-100V in lamps. And on 100V power is 100W for each. So why not answer 100W?

Comment: Show clearly what you have attempted so far, where is the solution you have already found - show that as well.

Comment: "And on 100V power is 100W for each. So why not answer 100W?"  So, 100W for each, then two of them isn't 100W ...

Answer (score 2):

> My attempt - According to me voltage divided half half and each bulb get 100V and produce 100 watt.

That's right. For two identical lamps in series, the voltage is split equally across the two lamps. That means each lamp gets its rated 100v, and so produces 100 watts. Total power for two lamps, 200 watts.

Comment: So 100W is the answer to my question. Right?

Comment: Yes, as I said, each lamp consumes 100 watts.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your Doubt 2. I think your understanding is flawed. To find how voltage is divided between the bulbs in series connection, you have to find the resistances of the bulbs first.  Just because both are 100 V rated bulbs, it doesn't mean that they will drop 100V - 100 V each when supply voltage = 200V. The power rating of bulb should also be considered. If the rated voltage of  bulb is V, and the rated power is P,  then Resistance of the bulb = \$ R=  V^2/P\$ . Now you can use voltage divider formula to find respective voltage drops across the bulbs and the Power given by them. Anyway in this case both bulbs are of same voltage and power rating, so both will drop 100 V each in series connection , and hence both will output 100 Watts.

Comment: +1 it is worth mentioning though that this only works for things like bulbs that increase their resistance with increased temperature causing a balancing effect. It is different with things like motors. Further, if the bulbs are different physical sizes, the initial startup may cause the smaller one to burn out before the other heats up.

Comment: Yes true.......

Answer (score 1):

> Two 100W, 100V lamps are connected in series across 200V supply. The power consumed by each lamp in watts will be?

## Assumptions

First one has to assume here that "lamps" means your typical [incandescent light bulb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incandescent_light_bulb) and that they are physically identical. If the bulbs are some other technology, the simple answer may not apply.

[image]

## Simple Answer

An incandescent lightbulb is simply a piece of thin wire which has a resistance. When you apply a voltage to the light bulb, current is passed through that resistance and it heats up. When it gets very hot, it emits light.

At it's nominal operating point, a 100W, 100V light bulb therefore has a resistance of  \$Volts^2/Power\$. In your example \$100^2/100 = 100\Omega\$.

As such, with two identical light bulbs in series you have a simple voltage divider circuit like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpSqDB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Since each lamp sees 100V, they will each dissipate 100W.

## More Complicated Answer

If you use an ohm-meter and measure the resistance of a cold 100W/100V lightbulb you will find the resistance is nowhere near \$100\Omega\$, in fact it will be a lot less.

This is because, when cold, it has a low resistance. As part of the heating process the resistance of the wire climbs. This is shown on the graph below for a different bulb.

[image]

That translates into a steady-state voltage/current relationship as shown here.

[image]

Now when you take two bulbs and put them in series, the supply voltage is shared between them as we described earlier. So if one has more volts across it the other has proportionally less. You can then plot the effect using a cross-over graph like this.

[image]

As you can see, the two curves cross over, that is, the current in both lamps is equal, at the middle voltage and the system balances. If one side were to take too much voltage it's resistance would increase while the other's would decrease, driving it back into balance so each bulb dissipates half the total power.

Of course, in reality the bulbs will never be identical. Each will be in some manufacturing tolerance range. They will however balance somewhere close to the mid-point.

## Why does that matter?

Note in my assumptions I said two identical bulbs. The thermal characteristics of the bulb are dependent on the physical nature of the bulb itself and how it is mounted or enclosed.

[image]

When first turned on, if the two bulbs are physically different or mounted and enclosed differently, each will take a different amount of time to reach their operating temperature. As such the crossover graph initially changes.

[image]

Notice now that the balance point where both are taking the same current gives one bulb a much higher proportion of the voltage.

In time everything will settle down to the normal operating point, however, the bulb that heats up fastest will be overloaded during the start-up, will flash very brightly, and may burn out.

## Other Technologies

Due to what I discussed above you can see that the thermal properties of the lamp type matters. Other technologies can act very differently with one lamp stealing all the power.

In particular LED lamps may not work the way you expect.

[image]

Since semiconductors in general have a negative temperature coefficient of resistance, meaning they get more conductive / less resistive as they get hotter, the thermal balancing effect is no longer available. Worse [thermal runaway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_runaway) can occur. As such, it is very important when using high power LEDs in series that they be thermally coupled so they stay close to the same temperature.